# Need some help with VLC

Tags: vlc

I am using VLC media player to play a .flac white noise sound that is about 10 minutes long.  Every time it repeats I notice a very noticeable stop in the loop unlike windows media player where it seamlessly transitions to the beginning of the song when it repeats.  How can I reduce this or what other media players can I try that can play a .flac?  Ty

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues persuading VLC to do seamless gaps in playlists.

To the best of my ability to detect the gaps, with the tracks I have at hand (no white noise I'm afraid), Kodi/OpenELEC seems to be effective for gaplessly looping flacs using a Pi 2 - other Kodi distributions may work as well, but I only have OpenELEC handy for testing.